# failed to manipulate my Arraylist

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2

I need help ,  I have an arrayList of objects . This object contains multiple fields I'm interested in this question by two date fields `(date_panne date_mise and running)` and two other time fields `(heure_panne and time start)`,
And  I would like to obtain the sum of the difference between `(date_panne, heure_panne)` and `(date_mise_en_marche; heure_mise_en_marche)` to give the total time of failure.
if someone can help me please I will be gratful this is my function :

```
public String disponibile() throws Exception {

    int nbreArrets = 0;
    List<Intervention> allInterventions = interventionDAO.fetchAllIntervention();
    List<Intervention> listInterventions = new ArrayList<Intervention>();

    for (Intervention currentIntervention : allInterventions) {
        if (currentIntervention.getId_machine() == this.intervention.getId_machine() 
            && currentIntervention.getDate_panne().compareTo(getProductionStartDate()) >= 0 
            && currentIntervention.getDate_panne().compareTo(getProductionEndDate()) <= 0) { 

            listInterventions.add(currentIntervention);
        } 
    }
    savedInterventionList = listInterventions; 

    return "successView" ;
}
```

Comment: Please, respect the Java naming conventions, and format your code properly. Choose meaninful variable names. mp1, mp2, getP1()... That makes your code unreadable, even for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for this remarques a will try to format my code properly ; concerning mp and mp2 , its name of arraylist , and getP1 anad getP2 this is getter for two date P1 (date of start production ) and  P2 its date of end production , thank you a lot

Comment: If you need to explain what a variable or method is, then it's badly named. Why not name the getters `getProductionStartDate()` and `getProductionEndDate()`? Isn't it much clearer?

Comment: ok I'll change it immediately

Comment: Err, no. Code in comments is unreadable. Click the edit link  at the bottom of your question, and paste your code there.

Comment: ok it's done thanks a lot to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the the dates are truncated to the day and are of type java.util.Date, and that the times only contain hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds and are also of type Date, start by creating a method like

```
private Date combine(Date dateOnly, Date timeOnly) {
    Calendar dateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    dateCalendar.setTime(dateOnly);
    Calendar timeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeCalendar.setTime(timeOnly);

    dateCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timeCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    dateCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, timeCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    dateCalendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, timeCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    dateCalendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, timeCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    return dateCalendar.getTime();
}
```

Now, it's simply a matter of looping through the interventions you want to sum, computing the difference between the dates as milliseconds, and add them:

```
long totalMillis = 0L;
for (Intervention intervention : interventions) {
    Date marche = combine(intervention.getDateMiseEnMarche(), intervention.getTimeMiseEnMarche());
    Date panne = combine(intervention.getDatePanne(), intervention.getTimePanne());
    long differenceInMillis = marche.getTime() - panne.getTime();
    totalMillis += differenceInMillis;
}
```

Comment: thanks Mr JB Nizet , I will try this proposition , but in my case the times are of time java.sql.Time ,I hope this is similar

Comment: java.sql.Time extends java.util.Date. It's similar.